# I don't know how to really enable extension in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

first of all i wanted to say that i'm real beginner
Some days ago i started using Visual Studio Code, and today i wanted to instal some extensios, every worked perfectly expect one, SmoothType, it's installed but when i read description of it i have to run some commands, there are they

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/spikespaz-forks/vscode-fix-checksums
$ cd vscode-fix-checksums/
$ npm install
$ npm install -g vsce
$ vsce package
$ code --install-extension vscode-fix-checksums-1.1.0.vsix
```

but question is where i have to type this commands, and how?
I tried to do it in terminal but this doesn't work
ty for any help first of all

Comment: Those commands are for compiling the extension from source and then installing the result. If you already installed this extension from the marketplace, you don't need to do any of this.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spikespaz.vscode-smoothtype or just type `Smoothtype` in the extension bar and install